# Failed Validation Messages

Tags: security

Here is the question I have been posed:

"What is the best way to handle in valid credentials when logging into a site. Do we tell the user if their username was invalid? Or likewise if their password is invalid?"

I did some searching, but I'm having trouble finding a site with some best practices for this, to refer them to.

My Question for the community here:
Does anyone here know a site that has some good guidelines/best practices for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most authoritative discussion I can find on this issue is from the "Web Security Testing Cookbook," Recipe 12.8.

The book points out:

1. You should provide a generic message indicating either the username or password was incorrect; revealing that just the username is correct allows attackers to enumerate valid usernames.
2. Account lockout functionality, after X number of tries, also carries the same risk; attackers can lockout accounts to find out if the usernames were valid or not.

You can read the whole "recipe" via Google Books here:
http://books.google.com/books?id=VmrSJ3V-s_MC&lpg=PA249&ots=cU7V62FQOA&dq=web%20security%20reveal%20valid%20username&pg=PA248#v=onepage&q=web%20security%20reveal%20valid%20username&f=false

Answer (score 5):

Just say that their credentials were incorrect.

Telling them that one piece of information was correct means that you're helping hackers discover user names at the very least.

If I enter:

> admin
>
> Password1

for example and I get a response that the password was invalid I now know that there is a user called "admin" on you system. I can now just vary the password in an effort to gain access.

If the response was "invalid user name or password" then I'm no wiser about whether there is a user called "admin" or not.

Comment: +1 There's probably not a site that will cover this in depth because this is about all there is to it.

Comment: I understand this and explained this to them. However they asked for some "best practices" and I couldn't find anything published by a reputable source, so I was hoping someone here might know of something.

Comment: @Sam - Like Scott I don't know of anywhere that covers this specifically, sorry. Isn't Stack Overflow a reputable source ;)

Comment: @ChrisF .... I don't know if our customer who has paid lots of money wants to here "Just go read the comments on Stackoverflow" :)

Comment: @Sam - I can understand that ;)